# How to find roots for particular value of gain "K" using Root Locus method in Julia?

Tags: julia, controlsystems.jl

I am looking for a method to calculate the numerical values of the roots of a function using the root locus method in Julia. I have found some documents to plot the root locus but couldn't find a method to get the numerical values of those roots for particular 'K'.

```
using ControlSystems
    K = 100
    a = 5
    b = 10
    G = 1 + K^b / (x^(b-1) * (x - a))
```

I want to find the roots of "G" using the root locus method in Julia.

Could you please help?

Thank you

Comment: Adding some code / example / expected output helps greatly with getting good feedback.

Comment: Dear @DanGetz, I have edited the question with the problem I want to solve. Please let me know if there is any way to solve it.

Comment: I'm not a control theory expert. But regarding the code, how is ControlSystems package used? It seems it is a bunch of constants, going into an equation in `x`. The equation in X is of degree 10, so it should have 10 complex solutions? How is this related to Control Systems? Look at https://juliamath.github.io/Polynomials.jl/stable/ for various root finding routines.

Comment: I belive you can use `rlocus` function from [FractionalSystems.jl](https://docs.juliahub.com/FractionalSystems/t5dWE/0.1.3/rlocus/)

Answer (score 0):

The function `rlocusplot` is available if you import the full `ControlSystems` package as opposed to just `ControlSystemsBase` (downside is a very long initialization time).

This worked for me:

```
using Plots, ControlSystems
plotly()

s = tf("s")
K, b, a = 100, 10, 5
G = 1 + K^b / (s^(b-1) * (s - a))
rlocusplot(G)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ITA. It is beneficial. Is it possible to get the numerical values of roots in addition to the plot? So that I can use those numerical values in the other part of a code.

Comment: You can also just compute the roots for a particular gain:
`poles(feedback(gain*G))` or just `poles(feedback(G))` if the gain is already built into `G`